# Internet Explorer 11 Group Policy Disable Find Files via F3 within the browser not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11

The policy, located at User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Search: Disable Find Files via F3 within the browser, does not work for IE11.
This policy was designed only for IE5 and IE6

I've also attempted adding a registry entry:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions\NoFindFiles
Type: DWORD
Data: 1
```

This has not worked either to disable it.

The environment is composed of a 2012r2 Active Directory system with Windows 7 and above workstations.

Does anyone have any solutions to implement this for the latest version of IE?

Answer (score -1):

F3 is 'Find on this page' in IE.  It does a text search of the current page.  Not sure where files come into it.

You're trying to use a IE5 or IE6 GPO/registry entry to configure IE11.  You should find the admin templates for IE11 and find what you need there. Google says they're [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40905).

Whether the feature you want is available is an exercise for you.

Comment: The admin templates for IE11 are installed. However, this policy is not part of it.

The intended function is as follows:

Users cannot press F3 to search the Internet (from Internet Explorer) or to search the hard disk (from Windows Explorer). If the user presses F3, a prompt appears that informs the user that this feature has been disabled.